# Does FusedLocationProviderClient offers some performance advantages over GoogleApiClient implemented the right way?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-play-services, android-gps

I'm thinking in upgrading an existing app I have in order to start using FusedLocationProviderClient for dealing with the location feature. My previous implementation has been working for a long time without issues, best practices were implemented, etc.
I see the new FusedLocationProviderClient has a less error prone approach, but my questions is:

Would I get an increased GPS performance (faster and more accurate location) by using the new approach assuming the old approach is implemented using the best practices suggested by Google and has been working without issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this has nothing to do with GPS accuracy (which is a factor of atmospheric conditions, GPS hardware, etc) or even location accuracy on fused locations.  Its just a more convenient API for initializing your connection to Google Play Services.